# Visual Basic 2010 DataSet

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, dataset

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and I'm working on a windows application form. I'm struggling with our database. I can connect and retrieve Data in the Grid View.

But I don't want to display the records - I want to put a specific row column in a variable (in short I want to work with it).
My `DataSet` is called `ProductionDataSet`. The `Table` is called `Employee` and has four columns called `Employee`, `First_Name`, `Last_Name` and `Status`.

How do I now store lets say the entry in column 4 and row 5 in the variable x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you connect to the databse you need to put the data into a DataTable and then manipulate the Row Items

```
' DataSet/DataTable variables
Dim ProductionDataSet As New DataSet
Dim dtProductionDataTable As New DataTable
Dim daProductionDataAdapter As New OdbcDataAdapter

' Variables for retrieved data
Dim sEmployee As String = ""
Dim sFirstName As String = ""
Dim sSurname As String = ""
Dim sStatus As String = ""

'Connect to the database 
''

'Fill DataSet and assign to DataTable
 daProductionDataAdapter.Fill(ProductionDataSet , "ProductionDataSet")
 dtProductionDataTable = ProductionDataSet.Tables(0)

'Extract data from DataTable
' Rows is the row of the datatable, item is the column

 sEmployee  = dtProductionDataTable.Rows(0).Item(0).ToString
 sFirstName  = dtProductionDataTable.Rows(0).Item(1).ToString
 sSurname  = dtProductionDataTable.Rows(0).Item(2).ToString
 sStatus  = dtProductionDataTable.Rows(0).Item(3).ToString
```